# UWP, For mediaplayerelement, how to override build in play button?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Basically, I am using mediaplayerelement, and with CustomMediaTransportControls with some custom buttons, I have one issue need to solve:

The media is set to autoplay, so when source is set, the playing starts, when pause button is clicked, the playing pauses, and the button changes to play state, now when play button is clicked, I want add a function before the playing starts, to first refresh and get a new source then play.

I really don't want to create my own media control if possible, so basically using build in transport control, just some how override playbutton_click, is this doable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `PlaybackStateChanged` event and check for `PlaybackState`

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    MediaPlayerElementName.MediaPlayer.PlaybackSession.PlaybackStateChanged += PlaybackSession_PlaybackStateChanged;
}

bool isFirst = true;
private void PlaybackSession_PlaybackStateChanged(MediaPlaybackSession sender, object args)
{
    if (sender.PlaybackState == MediaPlaybackState.Playing)
    {
        if (!isFirst)
        {
            //Set your New source
            isFirst = true;
        }
        else
            isFirst = false;
    }
}
```